# How can I get my output to display in a box item with renderUI and switch?

Tags: shiny, widget

I'm trying to create a dynamic UI. In this case, when a user selects a Program name, the professor box will only display the professor names who teach in that program. Based on the program, the professor ("prof") output should populate.

I've tried renaming things to see if I might have double-named items, but to no avail. When I run the app, the Professor box appears but it gives me no names based on the filtering of the program. No error is generated. I've looked at this for hours and not sure if I'm missing something so simple...

## UI

tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
    fluidRow(

```
selectInput("selectMode",label=h3("Select Mode"),
choices = c("Overall"="Overall")


),

box(width =3, solidHeader = T, background = "blue",

selectInput("selectProgram",label=h3("Select Program"),
choices = list( 
               "Social Work" = "SWO",
               "Nursing" ="NUR"))
               ),


uiOutput(outputId = 'course'),
uiOutput(outputId = 'prof')))
```

## Server

```
server <- function(input, output){

var <- reactive({
    switch(input$selectProgram, "Nursing" =  
    unique(
    indicators %>% filter(program=="NUR")%>%
        select(Professor)),

       "Social Work" = unique(indicators %>% 
       filter(program=="SWO")%>%select(Professor))
)
})

output$prof <- renderUI({
box(width =3, solidHeader = T, background = "blue",
selectInput("reactiveProfessor", "Select Professor", choices = 
var())
)
})
```

I want the Professor box to display names of the appropriate professors based on the program selection.

Comment: `selectInput("reactiveProfessor", "Select Professor", choices = 
var()$Professor` ?

Comment: I tried that and still doesn't generate any names.